# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to learn php
Im using php 7.0.1
Im using php mysqli
I saw a lot of problem like this but their solutions doesnt help me i think its because im using latest version and others uses previous version
**heres my php script:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../../db_connect.php';

$result = $db->query("select * from student where id = 1");

$personalinformation = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $personalinformation['username'];
?>
```

**heres my student table:**

```
id | username | password
1  | user1    | pass1
2  | user2    | pass2
3  | user3    | pass3
```

Comment: not enough info/code to support the question. check for errors.

Comment: Basically, `$result` is `false` instead of a mysqli-object. This is because the query fails. Add error-reporting ([`$db->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)) to your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited sorry

Comment: Where is `$id` defined? What does db_connect.php contain?

Comment: the db error is my threads title

Comment: your query failed, you failed to check for failure, and are now trying to use the boolean false you got back as if it was an object. e.g. NEVER assume success with db calls.

Comment: `db_connect.php` <= *Pandora's box*. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? other? credentials good? right db chosen? etc. check if the row exists `if()` and `while()`.

Comment: @ me if you need me. I am moving on now.

Comment: The title says *Call to a member function **fetch_array()** on boolean* but in the code you're doing *->fetch_assoc()*?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mentioned that im using mysqli

Comment: @RajdeepPaul what should i do? sorry im beginner

Comment: The error you specified in your title and the code have no corelation whatsoever. I think the problem is somewhere else in your code. Check that.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul  I found it, the student table was empty, sorry :( i did put 3 rows in my thread's table because i thought my student table wasnt empty.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i think the error appears because im trying to fetch an empty result.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul and i just notice that i put fetch_array() on my title, im really a pain in you guys sorry :( ill edit it. lol its embarassing i was wondering why you guys get upset with my title

Comment: @LorenceHernandez *Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean* means `$result` is `false`, which means your query execution has failed. Use [`mysqli::$error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to debug the issue.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I see i get it, that was Qirel pointing to me. thanks guys :)

Comment: @LorenceHernandez Glad to know that the issue is resolved. :-)

Comment: @LorenceHernandez: just because the syntax is perfect doesn't mean it can't fail for OTHER reasons. there's exactly ONE way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. if you think you can beat 1:infinity odds, good luck...